# Overlaying image with JS, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, overlay

I'm trying to create a dress-up function for my website which hugely resembles a typical dress-up game.. I've Goggleed but the closest answer is found is this one: [Overlaying image in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149769/overlaying-image-in-html)

I have tried to implement it with my own customizations on my local server and it worked! However, I tried to add a few things (like a fade transition) and it does not seem to work (the main functionality still worked). Worse, when I upload it to JSFiddle, the original functionality does not even work (much less the fade transition).

My code can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/DXeS9/1/)**. I have tried ways to solve it but my JS/HTML coding skills are limited. Basically I'm trying to add a fade-in transition to the change (rather than a sudden change). As to why the same code worked on my local computer but not on JSFiddle, I have no idea.

Finally, is there a way to set a default selection, instead of loading a "base"? Currently, a "base" image is being loaded, and only upon selection, the additional image layers appears. Can I preload the first selections in the list without the user selecting anything?

Thanks and greatly appreciate any help :)

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Funny Dress-up Games</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function createCharac(userChoice) {
      var links = [
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/ppl-red.jpg",
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/ppl-orange.jpg",
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/ppl-pink.jpg"
      ];

      document.getElementById('charac').src = links[userChoice];
    }

    function createPants(userChoice) {
      var links = [
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/pants-blue.png",
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/pants-green.png",
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/pants-yellow.png"
      ];

       document.getElementById('pants').src = links[userChoice];
     }

     function createShoe(userChoice) {
      var links = [
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/shoe-blue.png",
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/shoe-red.png",
        "http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/shoe-yellow.png"
      ];

      document.getElementById('shoe').src = links[userChoice];
    }
  //--></script>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .overlay-container {
    position: relative;
  }
  #char {
    z-index: 10;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #pants {
    z-index: 20;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #shoe {
    z-index: 15;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  -->
  </style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:8px;" onload="initImages();">
    <p>What character?
        <select name="choice1" id="choice1" onchange="createCharac(this.value)">
            <option value="0">Red</option>
            <option value="1">Orange</option>
            <option value="2">Pink</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>What pants?
        <select name="choice2" id="choice2" onchange="createPants(this.value)">
            <option value="0">Blue</option>
            <option value="1">Green</option>
            <option value="2">Yellow</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>What shoe?
        <select name="choice3" id="choice3" onchange="createShoe(this.value)">
            <option value="0">Blue</option>
            <option value="1">Red</option>
            <option value="2">Yellow</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <div class="overlay-container">
        <img class="overlay" src="http://dancer2dancer.sg/test/ppl-red.jpg" />
        <img class="overlay" id="charac" />
        <img class="overlay" id="pants" />
        <img class="overlay" id="shoe" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work: *open the JavaScript error console*, read and fix the errors. Then continue (with a question?).

Answer (score 1):

```
function initImages(params) {
  if(!params) {
    var params = {"character":0, "pants":0, "shoe":0}; // Default set
  }
  createCharac(params.character);
  document.getElementById("choice1").value = params.character.toString();

  createPants(params.pants);
  document.getElementById("choice2").value = params.pants.toString();

  createShoe(params.shoe);
  document.getElementById("choice3").value = params.shoe.toString();
}
```

Then you can use your function like this :

```
initImages({"character":0, "pants":2, "shoe":1});
```

or simply : `initImages()` to load the default set.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve a fade in/fade out effect, you might want to consider using a JavaScript library that supports you with the effects. For example, check out jQuery for a fade in/fade out effect (http://api.jquery.com/fadein/). What I would do there is:

1. Create a DIV for each part of the body you want to have changeable (currently, they're images).
2. Put default images into the DIVs.
3. Modify your "create" functions to fade out the existing images in DIVs, then either replace the img src with the new image, or create a new img object and have it fade in (in order to fade out and fade in in parallel).